# Firebase Realtime Database - download the already downloaded data

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to know how Firebase Realtime Database download works in below conditions:

1. Offline persistence is enabled

```
Database.database().isPersistenceEnabled = true
```

2. App is launched first time. Read the data from the same node in the below order

```
Database.database().reference().child("foo").child("uid1").observe(.childAdded) { snapshot in
print(snapshot)
}

Database.database().reference().child("foo").child("uid1").observe(.value) { snapshot in
print(snapshot)
}
```

What I observed are:

1. 'childAdded' observer will print the fresh data sequentially
2. 'value' observer will then bring the same but at once.

**My question is, will the data the value observer brings be from cache in this occasion?**

I've seen a few of similar questions([link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56183728/how-to-avoid-downloading-same-data-from-firebase-realtime-database), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27978078/how-to-separate-initial-data-load-from-incremental-children-with-firebase)) but I am not 100% sure that it is from cache and not fire the server to send the duplicated data. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If the data is present in the local cache, it'll be served from the cache. But this sounds like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): what is the actual problem you're troubleshooting, and can you show an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for that?

Comment: A couple of things; first, we need clarity on the issue per the above comment. Second, the *order* of your code is not relevant to how/when data is being read. Firebase is asynchronous and Firebase closures can resolve in different orders at different times. However, in this case a points; .childAdded events will fire before .value events - more importantly, are you wanting /foo/uid1 to generate an event every time *anything* changes in that node?

Comment: Sorry Frank and Jay for the late late reply. Although I wasn't able to answer your questions your comments helped me to go forward. Thank you.